# Dataprep: job finish event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

We are considering using Dataprep on an automatic schedule in order to wrangle & load a folder of GCS .gz files into Big Query.

The challenge is: how can the source .gz files be moved to cold storage once they are processed ?

I can't find an event that's generated by Dataprep that we could hook-up to in order to perform the archiving task.  What would be ideal is if Dataprep could archive the source files by itself.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to get notified when a job is done directly from Dataprep. What you could do instead is poll the underlying dataflow jobs. You could schedule a script to run whenever your scheduled dataprep job runs. Here's a simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# list running dataflow jobs, filter so that only the one with the "dataprep" string in its name is actually listed and keep its id
id=$(gcloud dataflow jobs list --status=active --filter="name:dataprep" | sed -n 2p | cut -f 1 -d " ")
# loop until the state of the job changes to done
until [ $(gcloud dataflow jobs describe $id | grep currentState | head -1 | awk '{print $2}') == "JOB_STATE_DONE" ]
do
# sleep so that you reduce API calls
sleep 5m
done
# send to cold storage, e.g. gsutil mv ...
echo "done"
```

The problem here is that the above assumes that you only run one dataprep job. If you schedule many concurrent dataprep jobs the script would be more complicated.